# Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ if $x^3 + x^2y + xy^2 + y^3 = 81$

Tags: derivatives

I need to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ if $x^3 + x^2y + xy^2 + y^3 = 81$

I am trying to first get y in terms of x, but that is quite lengthy and feels like I am doing something wrong. How do I go about this question?

Thanks,

Comment: A natural for implicit differentiation. You will not succeed in finding a useful formula for $y$ in terms of $x$. Neither would I.

Answer (score 6):

Use implicit differentiation:

$$3x^2+2xy+x^2\frac{dy}{dx}+y^2+2xy\frac{dy}{dx}+3y^2\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

Group the $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}(x^2+2xy+3y^2)=-3x^2-2xy-y^2$$

Isolate the $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\dfrac{3x^2+2xy+y^2}{x^2+2xy+3y^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

recall $$F=x^{ 3 }+x^{ 2 }y+xy^{ 2 }+y^{ 3 }-81$$ then we know $$\\ \frac { dF }{ dx } =-\frac { F_{ x }^{ \prime  } }{ { F }_{ y }^{ \prime  } } =-\frac { 3{ x }^{ 2 }+2xy+{ y }^{ 2 } }{ { x }^{ 2 }+2xy+3{ y }^{ 2 } } $$